# undeclared identifier when function is in cpp file

Tags: c++, vector, undeclared-identifier

I'm working on Space Invaders and in my Player Class I'm using a vector of a struct called point to store the coordinates of rockets. For some reason i'm getting "rocketVector : undeclared identifier" when I try to use it in the .cpp file.

Does anyone know why?

I'm still pretty new to C++ and I haven't been able to find a solution on google. it's starting to do my head in now :)

Thanks for any help!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
    Player(void);
    ~Player(void);
    void drawRockets(ISprite *r);
    vector<point> rocketVector;

};
```

Player.cpp

```
void drawRockets(ISprite *r) {

    // Draw appropriate number of rockets
    for(int i = 0; i < rocketVector.size(); i++){

        if( rocketVector[i].y < 0.0 ){                                             
        // Remove rockets off screen
            rocketVector.erase(rocketVector.begin() + i);
        } 
        else{
            rocketVector[i].y -= 20;                                        
            r->draw(int(rocketVector[i].x), int(rocketVector[i].y));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: include `<vector>` and use `std::vector`?

Comment: `#include "Player.h"` in your `.cpp`. Also, don't `using namespace ...` in a header file, this is extremely bad practice. Instead, use the `std::` prefix wherever necessary.

Comment: In addition to fixing the scope of your function and not `using namespace std;` in a header file (or at all), you are also completely obliterating the idea of encapsulation by declaring your rocketVector as `public`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `drawRockets` as a global function instead of a member function of the `Player` class.

Comment: @syam Please read the entire question: "For some reason i'm getting rocketVector : undeclared identifier"

Comment: @syam LOok at the error message again: "rocketVector : undeclared identifier".  Because in the global `drawRockets`, it doesn't know what `rocketVector` is.

Comment: Yeah, the title is a bit misleading.

Comment: @all Right, my bad. Looks like I read too fast, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify that `drawRockets` method is a member of the `Player` class:

```
void Player::drawRockets(ISprite *r) {

// Draw appropriate number of rockets
for(int i = 0; i < rocketVector.size(); i++){

    if( rocketVector[i].y < 0.0 ){                                             
        // Remove rockets off screen
        rocketVector.erase(rocketVector.begin() + i);
    } 
    else{
        rocketVector[i].y -= 20;                                        
        r->draw(int(rocketVector[i].x), int(rocketVector[i].y));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code :

- First, when you define a method outside its class, you have to specify it is in a class-scope during the declaration like :

  ```
  void Player::drawRockets( ISprite *r ) { ... };
  //   ^^^^^^^^
  ```

  this will solve your `"rocketVector : undeclared identifier"` error.

  *Here the operator of scope (`::`, two colons) is used to define a member of a class from outside the class definition itself.*
- Also, it is a very bad practice to to `using namespace ...` in a header file, you should avoid that.
- If you remove the `using namespace ...` don't forget to transform :

  ```
     vector<point> rocketVector;
  ```

  in

  ```
     std::vector<point> rocketVector;
  // ^^^^^
  ```